# Событие touchend неправильно работает

Tags: javascript, события

Для проверки делаю алерт на событии touchend но на айфоне это работает если нажать а потом отпустить и кликнуть, а в тех документации написано что это событие отпускания пальца, кто знает как на самом деле определить когда прикасаются и отпускают палец

Answer (score 2):

touchstart - Когда палец прикосается, touchend - когда отпускается.

Рекомендовал бы воспользоваться библиотекой, для обработки таких событий - http://hammerjs.github.io/. Сглаживает все браузерные "глюки", и добавляется поддержку таких событий, если таковой нет.

P.S. Документация на MDN по touch-events https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: дело в том что не хочется использовать разные сторонние библиотеки и плагины, touchstart вроде правильно работает но если привязать простой алерт к обоим этим событиям то touchend не срабатывает во время отпускания пальца на айфоне, он срабатывает если отпустить и кликнуть на элемент